# In R Shiny, how can you render outputs outside an observer where their names are reactives?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app where I have a dynamically created `tabsetPanel` where each tab contains a table. I do not know how many tabs/tables will be created in each session by users. I understand that it is bad practice to put `render*` functions inside `observe` or `observeEvent` calls but I can't think of any other way to do this. A minimal example of what I'm trying to do is shown below, which just picks a data set randomly to display on a given tab. Essentially, I'm trying to figure out how to call my table renderers without putting them inside an `observe`. More generally, although I have read it is bad practice to do this, I would also appreciate an explanation of exactly why it's not a good thing to do:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            numericInput("tabs", "Number of tabs", value = 5),
        ), 
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput("mytabset")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$mytabset <- renderUI({
        mytabs <- lapply(seq_len(input$tabs), function(x) {
            tabPanel(
                paste("Tab", x),
                tableOutput(paste0("tab", x))
            )
        })
        do.call(tabsetPanel, mytabs)
    })
    
    observe({
        set.seed(1)
        lapply(seq_len(input$tabs), function(x) {
            output[[paste0("tab", x)]] <- renderTable({
                sample(list(mtcars, iris, trees, cars), 1)
            })
        })
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used them in a while, but I think if you use [modules](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html), you can call them from outside of a reactive context, and won't need an observe..? :)